# Issue with importing my classes

Tags: python

Consider that I have 3 files.

I am trying to put different import function in one file and call that file i.e., File2 in this case directly.

File1.py

```
class generalTools(): 
     def waitAppear():
         wait()
```

File 11.py

```
class machinedata():
     def max():
         maxtime()
```

File2.py

```
import File1
import File11
self.generalTools = File1.generalTools()
self.machinedata=machinedata.max()
```

File3.py

```
from File2 import *
```

Note here I am not creating an object; just trying to call `File1->waitAppear()`

```
self.generalTools.waitAppear(self)
```

Whenever I execute above code, it throws error saying "generaTool has no instance"
What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: note the difference between waitApper (in your last code block) and waitAppear (in your File1.py).

Comment: I bet that your error message looks different than this. For once, it should trip on `self` being undefined. And there are other errors (typos?) and grammar mistakes (`machinedata` instead of `File11.machinedata` etc.).

Comment: Your methods lack a `self` attribute; presumably you simplified those away for the example?

Comment: @Vicky sorry.. by mistake i typed.. in code it is perfect.

Comment: @TimPietzcker in File2.py  Do i need put that code block in a class say.. class machine(self): def _init_ (self): ???

Comment: Your code is obviously incomplete, so we have no way of reproducing your problem. You need to reduce the code to the minimum required for us to run it and see the same error message as you.